# Prometheus returns "ranges only allowed for vector selectors"

Tags: prometheus

Here's my query, which is supposed to show the delta for each counter of the form `taskcnt.*`:

```
delta(label_replace({__name__=~"taskcnt.*"}, "old_name", "$1", "__name__", "(.+)")[1w])
```

I'm getting:

> Error executing query: 1:83: parse error: ranges only allowed for
>   vector selectors

Basically, without the `label_replace` I'll get:

> vector cannot contain metrics with the same labelset

How can I make this query work?

Comment: `label_replace({])` is already a query. You can either use sub-query with `[1w:]` instead of `[1w]` or, more easily, put the label replace on the outside of the expression: `label_replace(delta({...}[1w]),"old_name", ...)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Subquery is what you need indeed (credit to commenter above M. Doubez). This should work for you - it calculates the weekly delta by calculating the subquery each day (see `[1w:1d]`)

```
delta(label_replace({__name__=~"desired_metric_prefix_.+_suffix"}, "metric_name", "$1", "__name__", "desired_metric_prefix_(.+)_suffix")[1w:1d])
```

Be sure that all of the metrics that match your regex are compatible with the `label_replace` and with the `delta` functions. If you're displaying this in Grafana, use `Legend` expression `{{ metric_name }}` to display the extracted `metric_name` for each series.

Answer (score 6):

The `{__name__=~"taskcnt.*"}` may return multiple time series with identical set of labels, but with different metric names. For example, it may return the following time series:

```
taskcnt_foo{job="x",instance="y"}
taskcnt_bar{job="x",instance="y"}
```

As you can see, these time series have identical set of labels -  `{job="x",instance="y"}`, while they have different metric names: `taskcnt_foo` vs `taskcnt_bar`.

The [delta()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#delta) function  strips metric names from results, so it strips `taskcnt_foo` and `taskcnt_bar` names from the original time series and returns two time series with identical labelset - `{job="x",instance="y"}` when `{__name__=~"taskcnt.*"}` [series selector](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-series-selectors) is passed to it. This results in `vector cannot contain metrics with the same labelset` error, since the returned time series cannot be differentiated from each other.

Unfortunately Prometheus doesn't allow to use `label_replace()` or any other function inside `delta()`-like functions, which accept e.g. `range vector` - a [series selector](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-series-selectors) ending with square brackets (for example, `{__name__=~"taskcnt.*"}[1w]`).

There is a half-working solution by using [subqueries](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#subqueries), which is recommended in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67839845/274937). Unfortunately this solution has the following drawbacks:

- Prometheus subqueries may take significant amounts of additional CPU, memory and disk IO during execution, especially if the `interval` value is too small compared to the lookbehind `window` in square brackets: `[window:interval]`.
- Prometheus subqueries may miss original raw data during calculations when the `interval` in square brackets is too big.
- Prometheus subqueries are easy to mis-use if [their behavior](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#subqueries) isn't understood clearly.

These issues are addressed by [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/) in [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) with `keep_metric_names` modifier, which can be applied to any function. For example, the following MetricsQL query doesn't strip metric names from results, so it doesn't return  neither `vector cannot contain metrics with the same labelset` nor `ranges only allowed for vector selectors` errors:

```
increase({__name__=~"taskcnt.*"}[1w]) keep_metric_names
```