# Is it possible to get the average of histogram_quantile of the last t minutes?

Tags: prometheus, promql

What I'm intending to find is the average of the p99 latency in the last t minutes.

I tried this query, but it returned with the error "ranges only allowed for vector selectors"

```
avg_over_time(histogram_quantile(0.99, sum(rate(latency_buckets{service="foo"}[5m])) by (le))[5m])
```

From what I understand, what `histogram_quantile` does is return an instant value (let's say p99) and there is no way to get a series of p99 values over a specified interval. If so, are there any functions that can achieve the same goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible using [subquery](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#subquery) syntax:

```
avg_over_time(instant_query[interval:resolution])
```

An example with your query (avg over 1h):

```sh
avg_over_time(
  histogram_quantile( # the instant query
    0.99,
    sum(
      rate(latency_buckets{service="foo"}[5m])
    ) by (le)
  )[1h:] # subquery [ interval : resolution (by default == scrape interval)]
)
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks @anemyte !

Answer (score 0):

The above solution to use subquery works. Adding one more option just incase if using subquery is a performance concern for you as mentioned [here](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/#epilogue) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61169517/prometheus-returns-ranges-only-allowed-for-vector-selectors#:%7E:text=Prometheus%20subqueries%20may,isn%27t%20understood%20clearly.).

Before looking at alternate solution lets understand why the actual query in question fails.

The query result `histogram_quantile(0.99, sum(rate(latency_buckets{service="foo"}[5m])) by (le))` is a derived value not a raw value(stored in TSDB). Range vector selector can only be applied to raw values. outer [5m] cannot be applied to result which is derived result.

To get arround this we can store the result of inner query in TSDB by creating a recording rule for the inner query. So create recording rule for `histogram_quantile(0.99, sum(rate(latency_buckets{service="foo"}[5m])) by (le))` and use it in the outer query `avg_over_time(<recording_rule>[5m])`. Refer another similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77117711/query-to-find-maximum-request-rate-of-a-service-over-a-time-period-fails/77117713#77117713)