# Why range vector selector cannot be applied in nested fashion (fails with error)

Tags: prometheus, promql

Range vector selector [1d] used on top of a result e.g rate(xyz[5m]) fails.

Let us suppose we need to find maximum request rate of a service over a time period fails with the error message `bad_data: parse error: ranges only allowed for vector selectors`

```
max_over_time(
  rate(
    istio_requests_total{service=~"cms"}[5m]
  )[1d] 
)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to get the average of histogram\_quantile of the last t minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70255044/is-it-possible-to-get-the-average-of-histogram-quantile-of-the-last-t-minutes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that request rate `rate(istio_requests_total{service=~"cms"}[5m])` is not a raw value (value stored in TSDB), it is a derived value (result generated of a query). Range vector selector like [1d] selects ranges of time directly from TSDB.

Option #1:
You need to use prometheus subquery `([<duration>:<resolution>])` which allows you to run a range query (at specified or default resolution) on the subquery result. So use subquery as below

```
max_over_time(
  rate(
    istio_requests_total{service=~"cms"}[5m]
  )[1d:] 
)
```

Option #2:
The other option is to use recording rule for the rate expression `rate(istio_requests_total{service=~"cms"}[5m])`
and then use `max_over_time(<recording_rule_rate_expression>[1d])`.

Usually subqueries are costly the creating a recording rule for inner query is good idea.