# Filtering vector in promql

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I have a counter metric which may exist in a number of namespaces. If I need to calculate the rate for it, I can use:

`irate(counter{namespace="green"}[30m])`

and that works fine. However I need something a bit more complex: do the same rate calculation, but exclude points where the counter is equal to 0. So I can do this:

`counter{namespace="green"} > 0`

and it works fine. But if I try to get a rate on that, I get this:

```
irate((counter{namespace="green"} > 0)[30m])

parse error: ranges only allowed for vector selectors
```

Is there a way to filter the vector before applying rate calculation to it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prometheus returns "ranges only allowed for vector selectors"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61169517/prometheus-returns-ranges-only-allowed-for-vector-selectors)

Comment: Other than that, are you really sure what you are doing is a good idea? Because 0 is a valid value for a counters. I cannot imagine situation were what you want to do is appropriate.

Comment: @markalex in this particular case, 0 is not a valid value for the counter, it's an artifact of how metric is generated (you could call it a "bug" but it's hard to avoid it because of reasons).

Comment: Ok. If you understand what's going on then simply add : into you range selector, like this `[10m:]`