# prometheus max_over_time of 2 aggregated vectors

Tags: prometheus

I am a bit unclear as to why this query over the following gauges does not work:

```
max_over_time(
      (max(celery_queue_length{namespace="ns1"}) + 
      sum(celery_worker_tasks_active{namespace="ns1"}))[10m]
)
```

I can confirm that each of `max(..` and `sum(...` do return a valid series and I can actually query the result of the addition, but I can't seem to take a max over time.

Comment: Your query will result in an error "ranges only allowed for vector selectors". To solve it - use subquery syntax.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prometheus returns "ranges only allowed for vector selectors"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61169517/prometheus-returns-ranges-only-allowed-for-vector-selectors)

Comment: can you be more spcific, I don't see in those links any solution for the above.
I tried to do `sum_over_time(celery_worker_tasks_active[10m]) + max_over_time(celery_queue_length[10m])` and just got a "empty query result"

Comment: You need to add `:` into your range selector: `[10m:]`. Or specify some resolution, like `[10m:15s]`