# PromQL - how to use sum inside avg_over_time

Tags: promql

I am new to Prometheus, but am doing my best to use it to detect anomolous behaviour.
We have a system that has a background level of errors, and I'd like to create an alert to spot unusual increases.

I found a good [reference resource](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2019/07/23/anomaly-detection-using-prometheus/) that I'm trying to follow, but am hitting unexpectd syntactical problems.

If I try the following, I get a reasonable value, that looks good when charted:
`sum(rate(failure_count{error_code="8002"}[1h]))`
(summing due to the many contributions of pods as they wink in an out of existence).

The problem that I have is that when I surround this by either `avg_over_time` or `std_over_time` I get a syntax error:
`avg_over_time(sum(rate(failure_count{error_code="8002"}[1h]))[7d])`
`-> parse error: ranges only allowed for vector selectors`

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Please, at least google your error message, before you ask a question. SO has plenty of questions with this exact error message pointing to the use of subquery syntax.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prometheus returns "ranges only allowed for vector selectors"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61169517/prometheus-returns-ranges-only-allowed-for-vector-selectors)

Comment: In short, range selector `[7d]` can only be applied to simple vestor selector (like `my_metric{my_label="value"}`. Since you have something more complex - basically in your case, use `[7d : ]` instead.