# How to use rate to handle max_over_time

Tags: prometheus, promql

`http_requests_total` is a counter, because of some reasons, I need to use `max_over_time` to get a normal growth curve:

```
max_over_time(http_requests_total{}[5m])
```

Then I want to use rate to handle result of `max_over_time`, e.g.

```
rate(max_over_time(http_requests_total{}[5m])[1m])
```

I get an error executing the query:

> invalid parameter "query": 1:69: parse error: ranges only allowed for
> vector selectors

How could I do this query?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prometheus returns "ranges only allowed for vector selectors"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61169517/prometheus-returns-ranges-only-allowed-for-vector-selectors)

Comment: Also, why exactly do you think you need `max_over_time`? You have quite a normal/usual situation with counter and rate, and simple `rate(http_requests_total[1m])` should be OK.

Comment: @markalex because gunicorn has multiple processes, I follow
https://github.com/korfuri/django-prometheus/issues/89，
but not solved yet，I'm still researching.

Comment: ref this link https://github.com/korfuri/django-prometheus/issues/419

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pls use this (adding ':'):

```
rate(max_over_time(http_requests_total{}[5m])[1m:])
```

[image]